# Different labels for instances of properties typed by the same class within the same view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to get a page rendered with different labels like this:

**Tool details**: ______________ //Description follows the label

**Hardware details**: _______ //Description follows the label

### View:

```
@model MyViewMode
@MyHelperFor(c => c.Tool.Description)
@MyHelperFor(c => c.Hardware.Description)
```

### View model:

```
public class MyViewMode
{
    public SubPropertiesVM Tool { get; set; } = new Tool ();
    public SubPropertiesVM Hardware { get; set; } = new Hardware ();
}

public class SubPropertiesVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SubPropertyLabel { get; set; }
}
```

If I let the system default to the property name, then I would get the same label for all instances.

I could decorate `Description` in the `SubPropertiesVM` class `[DisplayName("Some label")]`, but then, again, the same text "Some label" would be rendered twice in the page.

I thought of assigning a different value to `SubPropertyLabel` upon each initialization, and then somehow make Razor utilize it. But, my understanding is that `[DisplayName("")]` does not take a variable as a parameter.

My helper has an optional parameter, and sets it as the label. That does work fine. However, each view model is used in several views. I would prefer not to manually and repetitively set the label on each view, but set it only once for each view model.

Is it possible to set in `MyViewModel` the label texts for properties in `SubPropertiesVM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize the properties when you create them, like this:

```
public SubPropertiesVM Tool { get; set; } = new Tool ()
{
    Description = "Tool",
    SubPropertyLabel = "ToolLabel"
};
```

Do the same for `Hardware` property, of course with another description etc.

Then `Tool` and `Hardware` will get different descriptions.

Comment: Thanks @PoulBak. I think that you meant `= new SubPropertiesVM()`.

Comment: I used `new Tool()` because that is what you have in the code shown. But `new SubPropertiesVM()` will definitely work.